# FSCK only output: fsck from util-linux 2.26.2

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, fsck, testdisk

When I run `fsck` on my Ubuntu the only output I get is below:

```
root@administrator-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:/home/administrator# fsck /dev/sdc1 -r
fsck from util-linux 2.26.2
```

I don't believe it's running, is there any way for me to fix it or any other application I can run to check and repair an NTFS drive that wasn't disconnected properly like in windows?

Comment: With NTFS you should use `ntfsfix`

Comment: @muru Thanks. `ntfsfix` was able to fix error `$MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0)`